# Diagram hangs after linkvalidation returns false in GOJS diagram

Tags: gojs

I am using GoJS for diagram creation and using version 1.8.33, And i want to apply validations while drawing links between the nodes. so I used

```
this.diagram.toolManager.linkingTool.linkValidation = isDrawLink;
isDrawLink(fromnode, fromport, tonode, toport) {
return fromnode.data.name!==tonode.data.name
}
```

but when this function return false my diagram hangs i cannot do anything on my diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this code, which includes your link validation function:

```
  function init() {
    var $ = go.GraphObject.make;

    myDiagram =
      $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",
          {
            "linkingTool.linkValidation": function(fromnode, fromport, tonode, toport) {
              return fromnode.data.name !== tonode.data.name;
            }
          });

    myDiagram.nodeTemplate =
       $(go.Node, "Auto",
         $(go.Shape,
           { fill: "white", portId: "", fromLinkable: true, toLinkable: true, cursor: "pointer" },
           new go.Binding("fill", "color")),
         $(go.TextBlock,
           { margin: 8 },
           new go.Binding("text"))
       );

    myDiagram.model = new go.GraphLinksModel(
      [
        { key: 1, text: "Alpha", color: "lightblue", name: "A" },
        { key: 2, text: "Beta", color: "orange", name: "E" },
        { key: 3, text: "Gamma", color: "lightgreen", name: "A" },
        { key: 4, text: "Delta", color: "pink", name: "E" }
      ]);
  }
```

I was unable to reproduce any problem.  I tried both 1.8.33 and 2.0.3.